# Saving a complex number in a variable

Tags: c++, complex-numbers

I am trying to perform this computation which results in a complex number. However, C++ gives me "NaN".

```
double Q, r, Theta;
Q=-0.043543950754930;
r=0.009124131609174;
Theta=acos(r/sqrt(pow(-Q,3))); 
// result must be (0.00000000000000 + 0.0911033580003565i)
```

Comment: `acos(x)` takes a double and returns a double.  It can't return a complex value (which would be two doubles).  You need to do the calculation yourself (using non-complex functions) or use a library that works with complex numbers.

Comment: Read into [`std::complex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) and related functions.

Comment: Why you don't use `std::complex`?

Comment: *"but C++ give me 'nan'."* -- Did this surprise you? You declared `Theta` to be a `double`, a type that stores real numbers. Your desired result is ***n***ot ***a*** real ***n***umber, a.k.a. "nan".

Answer (score 5):

Yes, by using the [std::complex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) type:

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::complex<double> Q = -0.043543950754930;
    std::complex<double> r = 0.009124131609174;
    std::complex<double> Theta = std::acos(r / std::sqrt(std::pow(-Q, 3)));
    std::cout << Theta << '\n';
}
```

Note that the complex functions return values in specific ranges. You may have to adjust for this if you are looking for a specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to perform this computation which results in a complex number.

All the variables in the posted snippet are of type `double`, so that the compiler has to use the overloads of `std::acos`, `std::sqrt` and `std::pow` accepting parameters of type `double` and returning `double` values.

In particular, the function `double std::acos(double arg)`<sup>[1]</sup>:

> If a domain error occurs, an implementation-defined value is returned (**NaN** where supported).
> [...]
> Domain error occurs if `arg` is outside the range [-1.0, 1.0].

Given the values of `R` and `Q` in the posted example, the value of `arg` is *greater* than 1, causing a domain error.

To obtain a complex value, the OP should use (or cast to) variables of type `std::complex<double>`, so that the "correct" overloads of the mathematical functions are chosen, as well as the expected return type.

They could also implement different numerical algorithms (one for real, one for complex values) and let the program choose the right path based upon the value of some "discriminant" variable. E.g. a cubic equation has three complex solutions in general, but those can either be three different real values or three real values (two coincident) or one real value and two complex conjugate ones. A program might use different methods instead of a single general (all complex) one.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Quotes from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/acos, emphasis mine.